# There are no positive integers, $x$ and $y$, such that $x^2-3xy+2y^2=10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove or disprove the following proposition:

> There are no positive integers $x$ and $y$ such that:
>   $x^2−3xy+2y^2=10$

Thanks!

Comment: Why should we do that?

Comment: Please review [ask].  Consider adding context to your Question.  What approach did you try?  What difficulty was encountered?  How is this problem an interesting one?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x^2−3xy+2y^2=(x-2y)(x-y)=10$.

Answer (score 0):

$$(x-2y)(x-y)=10=2\times 5=5\times 2=-2\times (-5)=-5\times (-2)$$
or
$$(x-2y)(x-y)=10=1\times 10=10\times 1=-1\times (-10)=-10\times (-1)$$
For example
\begin{cases}
x-2y=2\\
x-y=5
\end{cases}
we have $x=8$ and $y=3$